# What data structure should i use for caching ordered entities

Tags: caching, data-structures

I need to store in cache some items, like chat messages. I also need to slice these items on the key value range. For example (back to chat messages) the most common operation with cache will be getting chat messages from begin date to end date.

What data structure should I be considering? I was thinking about simple array, but it will work for O(n). Is there any data structure that will work faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self balancing binary search tree like Red-Black Tree which stores the entries in ordered fashion and will provide the insert,delete,search in O(logn) in both average and worst case.

So when you need the chat message between a date interval you can search your RB-tree for data range which are already ordered.

Answer (score 0):

use an associative set, store you data in an `array<data>`, but use a hash table to store `pair<data , arrayIndex>`. this way you can search , insert and delete with o(1).

Comment: I think, you missed the point. I don't need to get single chat message, i need to slice the sequence by some property. So the hash table is not a considerable option.